# MongoDB keeps giving me null

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have some difficulty in getting Mongodb aggregate to work. It keeps giving me null. Please help. Below are the codes written in php. Thanks.

What I want to do is to sum up the values of 2 fields, Requests and Responses, between 2 particular dates

```
    try {
        $mongodb = new MongoClient("mongodb://ad:pass2word1@localhost");

        $database = $mongodb->selectDB('backend');
        $collection = new MongoCollection($database, 'RequestSummary');

        $pipeline = array(
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array(
                        'request' => array('$sum' => '$Requests'),
                        'response' => array('$sum' => '$Responses')
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'RequestDate' => array(
                        '$gte' => intval($_SESSION['range_from']),
                        '$lte' => intval($_SESSION['range_to'])
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
        var_dump($g);
    } catch (MongoConnectionException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` of your `$group` can't contain aggregation operators like `$sum`.  Those sums need to be defined as fields at the same level as `_id`.  If you don't want to group on a specific field you can use `NULL` for the `_id` like this:

```php
 array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => NULL,
        'request' => array('$sum' => '$Requests'),
        'response' => array('$sum' => '$Responses')
    )
),
```